# Display results between dates sql

Tags: mysql

I am wanting to display results where the date stored in the table is not between the dates specified in the query.

Here is the current SQL query

```
SELECT accounts_cstm.statusdescription_c,
       users.user_name,
       accounts.name,
       accounts_cstm.account_number_c,
       DATE_FORMAT(MAX(calls.date_modified),'%Y/%m/%d')
FROM accounts
LEFT OUTER JOIN calls ON accounts.id = calls.parent_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON accounts.assigned_user_id = users.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN accounts_cstm ON accounts.id = accounts_cstm.id_c
AND accounts.deleted <> 1
WHERE
        (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MAX(calls.date_modified),'%Y/%m/%d')
         FROM calls) NOT BETWEEN '2014/06/25' AND '2014/07/02'
    AND users.user_name = 'CBennet'
    AND accounts_cstm.chkcustomer_c = '1'
GROUP BY accounts.name
```

I get a full list of results but I get results that shouldn't appear ie results with calls.date_modified that is in between the dates specified.

See below for an example of a wrong result, you can see that the date to the right is in between the dates `2014/06/25` and `2014/07/02` therefore this shouldn't appear.

[image: img]

Can someone let me know what i'm doing wrong here?

Within the table calls, date_modified is stored in the following format 2014-06-10 10:55:47

Comment: Is there really a need for inner select under the WHERE command? I don't think it's right to use the inner select in this scenario, the condition will be read as `WHERE True` if the MAX(calls.date_modified) is not between the 2 dates instead of filtering your outer select.

Comment: Try `where DATE_FORMAT(MAX(calls.date_modified),'%Y/%m/%d') not between '2014/06/25' and '2014/07/02' AND
users.user_name = 'CBennet' .....` instead of the inner select statement.

Comment: Sky: when i change (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MAX(calls.date_modified),'%Y/%m/%d') FROM
calls) to DATE_FORMAT(MAX(calls.date_modified),'%Y/%m/%d') i get error "invalid use of group function"

Comment: Because you need to `group by accounts_cstm.statusdescription_c, users.user_name, accounts.name, 
accounts_cstm.account_number_c` all of them, not accounts.name only

Comment: Maybe you should show the whole select query is like now instead of censoring here and there. From what I see you're selecting 5 columns but your screenshot only show 3 columns? Are you sure you're running the right query.

Comment: Sky: still receiving the same error even when grouped by all of them.

Comment: I am using PHP to output the results, therefore I am only selecting 3 columns

Comment: Use mysql to test your queries first. What's the current result you're getting?

Comment: I am testing it within phpmyadmin and I am receiving the same error

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT *
FROM `test`
WHERE (date NOT BETWEEN '2012-01-30 14:15:55' AND '2014-09-29 10:15:55')
```

I created test table with some test values at sqlfiddle and got desired output http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ffb7/4